# How to align items to center on mobile and left on desktop in tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I tried some thing like this

```
<div className="flex w-full lg:justify-start md:justify-center sm:justify-center sm:items-center">
  <Button title={data.title as string}></Button>
</div>
```

But it is always left aligned on mobile. It should be center on mobile and left on desktop

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="flex w-full sm:justify-center lg:justify-start">
  <Button title={data.title as string}></Button>
</div>
```

make sure to add the flex class to the parent container to enable flexbox behavior

Answer (score 0):

In the `div`, use `'class'` instead of `'className'` and use `max-sm` and `max-md` instead of `md` and `sm`.

```
<div class="flex w-full max-lg:justify-start max-md:justify-center max-sm:justify-center">
```

**Updated Play**: **https://play.tailwindcss.com/sYPSYnOC6R**

Comment: The alignment is always center in both desktop and mobile in playground you have shared

Comment: @kittu I am sorry, I wrote it from mobile, so missed it. I have updated the answer and the playground. Check it out. You should be using `max-sm` and `max-md` instead of `sm` and 'md'.